# MySQL default wait_timeout is 28800 but in my server I can see more than that value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, aws, waits, aurora

Im using **AWS MySQL Aurora**, the current wait_timeout is *28800* which is the default one, and interactive_waitimeout is also 28800.

But I can see more than the default value.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is a "keep-alive" ping of some sort.  Do you have some form of "connection pooling"?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! This one could be application framework has the value passed at the time of creating connection to DBs to set wait_timeout or interactive_timeout for their session level, ***this overrides default mysql settings.***

If you enable general log on any test environment and have their application to point to that DB. You will find wait_timeout or interactive_timeout setting such values.

**Short Term Fix:**

- You might consider killing connections that are more than 500secs in sleep state as a cron running every minute.

**Permenant Fix:**

- Have application team to fix their code, by not to pass any default values to DB.
- Once app is fixed, remove the cron that kills every minute.